# Проблема с fscanf

Tags: c, файлы

У меня такая проблема, в упор не понимаю, почему fscanf не хочет считывать из файла

```
// Из двух файлов создать третий, слив в нем первые половины
// элементов каждого из первоначальных файлов, в которых эти элементы удалить.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int n = 20;
    FILE* f1;
    FILE* f3;
    char name1[] = "file1.txt";
    int k;
    if ((f1 = fopen(name1, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл file1.txt");
        return 0;
    }

    f3 = fopen("file3.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        fscanf(f1, "%d ", &k);
        printf("%d ", k);
       // fprintf(f3, "%d ", k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, видимо, файл у вас все же открывается... Что у вас лежит в файле `file1.txt`? Потому что добиться вашего `fscanf` не хочет читать - у меня не получается. Если, конечно, файл есть и в нем текстово записаны целые числа...

Comment: В файле у меня числа через пробел расположены --> "1 2 3 4 5 6". Да, файл есть, и записывать я в него могу, получается, а вот считать - нет

Comment: Как вы поняли, что не получается прочитать файл? Какой вывод в консоли?

Comment: "-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460", т.е. он выводит ничего, в переменную k ничего не заносится почему-то, fscanf возвращает -1

Comment: У вас файл не в кодировке utf-8? И первые пару байт - не цифры, а признак этой кодировки?...

Comment: Покажите файл с данными. Похоже, проблема в нём.